# UFW not blocking incoming traffic

Tags: debian, firewall, ufw

I have a Debian 9 Server running UFW, and i'd like to block all incoming requests except on port 2122 (SSH), and 80/443 (For HTTP(s)).

I ran the following commands :

```
ufw reset
ufw default deny incoming
ufw default allow outgoing
ufw allow incoming 2122/tcp
ufw allow 80/tcp
ufw allow 443/tcp
ufw enable
```

Which compiles to :

```
ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2122/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
2122/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Seems like everything is fine, at least to me. But, when i run a docker container, on port 2424 (or, really, any other port), i can still access http://domain.tld:2424, despite the firewall.

I tried rebooting, restarting iptables, ... No dice.
Any suggestion ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker opens ports in the firewall itself, for any ports that are EXPOSEd by the running containers. These do not show up in `ufw` output, but can be viewed in `iptables`.

You should:

- Ensure that only ports that need to be accessible to the Internet are EXPOSEd.
- Use docker-compose to orchestrate the creation and running of multiple related containers. They can talk to each other without having to expose ports.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense. Didn't know Docker was interacting with iptables ! Works like a charm when using `expose` instated of `port`s. Thanks !